# Show new activity in the page title

Tags: feature-request, live-refresh

After asking a question, I may be interested in quick responses and react on comments quickly. So I leave the tab open. But I always need to check back to the tab to see whether there's a "something has been added" note somewhere, either a comment to the question, or a new answer or a comment update on an answer I already read. Couldn't this also be shown in the page title so I don't need to switch tabs all the time while I'm reading something else?

Comment: Interesting, the other question mentions an implemented feature that is not implemented for me. I have never seen this. So what's wrong here? May I request it being fixed or completed or enabled or whatever is required to make it work? The screenshots also only show list pages, but not the question page itself. Maybe this is the new part of my request? Please clarify. Right now it's no duplicate for me.